# Custom XMP data: Create namespace, or just plug it in somewhere?

Tags: xmp

If I am encoding arbitrary data into XMP is it better to use an existing namespace, or create my own? (NB:I barely know what I'm talking about)

I'm using [Exempi](https://libopenraw.freedesktop.org/wiki/Exempi/) to edit XMP meta on an AVI file:

```
exempi -w -n http:// TEST -s PROPERTY1 -v VALUE1 example.avi
```

Creates:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""
  xmlns:TEST="http://"> 
 <TEST:PROP1>VALUE1</TEST:PROP1>
</rdf:Description>
```

However, I don't have a URI (not even sure what it's for) and don't think this information will be universally accessible by other programs that read XMP.

Is there a standard place I should but arbitrary data in (say a "comment" field, perhaps serialized) that I can more universally ensure is most accessible by other programs?

Using exempi to add comment:

```
exempi -w -s xmpDM:logComment -v "a:2:{s:5:\"TEST1\";s:6:\"VALUE1\";s:5:\"TEST2\";s:6:\"VALUE2\";}" example.avi
```

Yields:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""
  xmlns:xmpDM="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/1.0/DynamicMedia/">
 <xmpDM:logComment>a:2:{s:5:"TEST1";s:6:"VALUE1";s:5:"TEST2";s:6:"VALUE2";}</xmpDM:logComment>
</rdf:Description>
```

Which appears to be more accessible by other programs (exiftool, properties dialogue of most major video players, etc)

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: 50 is all the bounty I can afford right now :P